# Chrome turns input field into multiline after adding and removing the very same class

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, blink

So I ran across this small issue I am kind of confused about. First the code:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input id="input" type="text" value="Some long long long text that doesn't fit into the input text field">
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="show(false)">
  hide
</button>

<button type="button" onclick="show(true)">
  show
</button>
```

CSS:

```
input {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute
}
```

JS:

```
var show = b => {
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  input.classList[b ? 'remove' : 'add']('hidden');
}
```

I have an `input` `type="text"` on a web page. As soon as I add an "hide/offset" class to its ancestor div and then I remove the very same class, the `input` turns its content to multiline (in case it was too long to be displayed in the field). The fiddle shows quite well what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/yq9x01r8/1/

Run in Chrome. Click the hide button, then click the show button.

[image: Resulting multiline field]

The `.hidden` class is added directly to the `input` in this example. In my page, it is added to one of the parents but it produces the same broken field (however, I am not able to reproduce it exactly like that, too much stuff and nesting going on).

Is there any reason why the input should be doing this? Is this a Blink bug? Any CSS that could prevent this? Please note I would prefer not to use `white-space: nowrap;` if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Chrome is not following standard rules - none of adding `!important` to the height rule, adding an `overflow: hidden;` rule, or making the selector for `#input` more specific,  prevents the input box from becoming multi-line.

However it may be an edge case - the `hidden` rule is rather bizarre. if you replace

```
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
```

with

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Chrome goes back to behaving as expected.

---

Regarding comment info, an alternative way to hide and show the input without changing its CSS is to hide and show its parent element:

```
var show = b => {
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  input.parentNode.classList[b ? 'remove' : 'add']('hidden');
```

This only salvaged Chrome's behavior if the parent node is displayed as a block element - attempts to wrap the `input` in a `span` tag without changing its display rule to "block" only resulted in re-appearance of the multi-line input element when the `hidden` class of the `span` element was removed.

If the existing `div` container has no other child elements, allowing it to be changed to an absolute element may be all that is needed.

The idea of trying this came from how CSS can fail when applied to an absolute block, but work if applied to a static block ( `position: static`) inside the same absolute block.

Comment: The rules come from the ExtJS framework, I just removed the bloat and found it is visibility + position that affects it. (there is also top: -xxxx and display: block). Visibility:hidden makes sense when you need to measure the dimensions of the element. You can't do that with display:none.